# SE sites seem to be ruining the fun by disallowing comments

Tags: discussion, moderation, comments

Example question: [Is Fox News correct that Mueller shouldn't be going after a campaign finance violation?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/30314/is-fox-news-correct-that-mueller-shouldnt-be-going-after-a-campaign-finance-vio)

This question isn't exactly tied to politics.se, it's simply the last place I happened to see it.

There will be a question, it will get some comments. Those comments do not help define or refine the question, but are instead funny, or commentary on the situation, or some other thing. They are not exactly "Me too" type comments, but they don't strictly help the question either.

Along will come someone with the correct privileges and delete all the comments (not move them to chat, which may be a bit better). While I do understand that a SE site is meant to be a kind of wiki of information, it seems like it should also be fun. If you can't even have a little fun in the comments section, then why should one even bother coming to the site, other then to ask questions. And with no one coming to the site, who will create the high quality answers?

You can see a kind of example of this (though to be fair there is no real proof) with busy, and popular, SE sites. Their comments are often fun in nature. Sometimes moved to conversation. But none-the-less the rule of the comment must clarify the question or answer is not followed as strictly.

It seems to me that "disallowing" fun comments, hurts the overall site. Though I do understand the need to not turn the site into a forum.

Should we be more lax on the comments sections?

Comment: +1. The real deal is always in a one line comment, otherwise the question is too broad or poorly researched.

Answer (score 6):

No, we should not allow "fun" comments.

The goal of this community is to provide factual answers to political questions from a neutral point of view. We want to generate content which can be considered an acceptable source of information regardless of one's political views. Unfortunately we aren't 100% successful in this regard. This website's community is [frequently accused](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=bias) of being politically biased in one direction or another.

Regardless of whether those accusations are justified or not, allowing people to "jokingly" humiliate other viewpoints would just reinforce that impression. It would attract users who think that biased viewpoints are OK to express on this website and alienate those users whose viewpoints are made fun of.

And besides, such comments rarely fulfill [the purpose of comments](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment): To improve the question/answer they get posted under.

For further reading I recommend [Why do we hate fun at Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284390/why-do-we-hate-fun-at-stack-exchange/284406) on the general meta stack exchange.

Comment: While I agree with you when such comments may give off a perception of bias, this is not always the case. Would you be equally as opposed to 'fun' comments that do not have the potential to be interpreted as political commentary or biased?